# Why tensorflow saver meta file is getting large?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Far as I know, a meta file for saver is for the information of model like structure and operation. So the file size should be same, but the first meta file size is much smaller than the last meta file. Why does this happen?

In addition, if I set 'write_meta_graph'=false, there is no meta file at all. Then how to restore the model later?